# Facebook page plugin

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-iframe

First of all, happy new year!

I'm trying to add an iframe to my site using the **Facebook Page Plugin**.

I have used the generator from the FB site:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin

In this example I'm using "https://www.facebook.com/facebook", but the same problem occurs for my facebook page.

---

### **Iframe**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Ffacebook&tabs=timeline&width=0&height=0&small_header=false&adapt_container_width=true&hide_cover=false&show_facepile=true&appId" width="0" height="0" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

However this results in an empty page.

Notes:

- Problem occurs in every browser (Chrome, FireFox, IE)
- If I click the URL from the source code the URL loads
- Accessable from the web through https:// (not localhost)

---

### **JavaScript SDK**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/nl_NL/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

    <div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook" data-tabs="timeline" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/facebook" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook">Facebook</a></blockquote></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

This method also returns an empty page; the *link* to the facebook page appears for 1 second and then dissapears.

Notes:

- Changed "//connect.facebook.net..." to "https://connect.facebook.net..."
- Firebug does not show any error
- Accessable from the web through https:// (not localhost)

---

Any suggestions? None of the Stackoverflow/Google results helped me so far.

Thanks!

Comment: did you check out the console of chrome? it´s much better than firebug, i had a lot of bugs with firebug (the name implies that it comes with a lot of bugs, lol)

Comment: @luschn: thanks for your reply. Yes, I did check it, just double checked, no errors :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently nothing was wrong; a week later it just worked without any edits. Looks like FB changed (fixed?) something.. :)